# Grep how to find word with only one symbol from range?

Tags: grep

I should find lines, where the last word is only with one vowel. I was trying this

```
grep '[aeiou]\w{1}$'
```

My file:

```
asdja asjd ncma
dnsajd asd m asnndna
jdasjdn masi
mdmasdmams masdmasmdjq amsmd
```

Output should be:

```
asdja asjd ncma
mdmasdmams masdmasmdjq amsmd
```

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: grep '.* .*[aeiou].*' change the .* to letters.

Comment: @HagaiWild thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep '\b[^aeiou]*[aeiou][^aeiou]*$' file
```

Output:

```
asdja asjd ncma
mdmasdmams masdmasmdjq amsmd
```